# Stop scheduled job inside JobService in firebase jobdispatcher

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am using firebase jobdispatcher in my app, but i am facing an issue. i want to stop job after task is completed . i tried calling `selfStop()` inside `onStartJob()` method. But its `onStopJob()` never gets called. As per requirement in my app i am finishing the activity which starts the job. So can anyone tell me how can i stop job inside `JobService` class.

Code sample:

// Create a new dispatcher using the Google Play driver.

```
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job downtimeOverNotificationJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(AppJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
                .setTag("my-unique-tag")        // uniquely identifies the job
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(20,20))
                .build();
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(downtimeOverNotificationJob);



  @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Job started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
            //Do something after 10000ms
            stopSelf();

        }, 5000);
        return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        }else{
            //deprecated in API 26
            v.vibrate(500);
        }
        return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Need to call jobFinished(job, false) if you want to restart job manually and get onStartJob(JobParameters job) callback.

Example:

     @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Job started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                //Do something after 10000ms
               jobFinished(job, false);

            }, 5000);
            return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            }else{
                //deprecated in API 26
                v.vibrate(500);
            }
            return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
        }
```

Comment: I could not understand it, can you show some piece of code.

Comment: it does not call onStopJob() , i tried this. How can i know if job is dismissed or stopped.

Comment: jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );

It gives you all of your jobs\